# Django chunked upload in IIS

Tags: django, iis, blueimp, chunks

I uploaded a program on which a django application is used for file uploading and used the chunk file uploads for it (with the blueimp fileupload on JS side).

When I tested my application locally, it works. When I do it on the IIS production, I always get this error:

POST http://URL/api/chunked_upload/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

The logs in the IIS were not helpful either.

JS Code:

```
$('#fileUpload').fileupload({
        url: window.location.href + 'api/chunked_upload/',
        dataType: "json",
        maxChunkSize: 100000, // Chunks of 100 kB
        formData: form_data,
        type: 'POST',
        add: function (e, data) {
            form_data.splice(1);
            calculate_md5(data.files[0], 100000);
            $("#submitButton").off('click').on("click", function () {
                showLoading()
                data.submit();
            });
        },
      chunkdone: function (e, data) { // Called after uploading each chunk
        if (form_data.length < 2) {
          form_data.push(
            {"name": "upload_id", "value": data.result.upload_id}
          );
        }
      },
      done: function (e, data) { // Called when the file has completely uploaded
        let formInput;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: window.location.href + 'api/chunked_upload_complete/',
          data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf,
            upload_id: data.result.upload_id,
            md5: md5
          },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
                inputForm = document.getElementById('ddGraderForm')
                document.getElementById('id_formFile').value = data['file']
                inputForm.submit()
             }
        });
      },
    });
```

Django urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.webinterfaceViews, name='main'),
    path('api/chunked_upload_complete/', FastaFileUploadCompleteView.as_view(), name='api_chunked_upload_complete'),
    path('api/chunked_upload/', FastaFileUploadView.as_view(), name='api_chunked_upload'),
]
```

Django view

```
class FastaFileUploadView(ChunkedUploadView):

    model = fileUpload

    def check_permissions(self, request):
        # Allow non authenticated users to make uploads
        pass

class FastaFileUploadCompleteView(ChunkedUploadCompleteView):

    model = fileUpload

    def check_permissions(self, request):
        # Allow non authenticated users to make uploads
        pass

    def on_completion(self, uploaded_file, request):
        # Do something with the uploaded file. E.g.:
        # * Store the uploaded file on another model:
        # SomeModel.objects.create(user=request.user, file=uploaded_file)
        # * Pass it as an argument to a function:
        # function_that_process_file(uploaded_file)
        pass

    def get_response_data(self, chunked_upload, request):
        return {'file': chunked_upload.file.name, 'filename': chunked_upload.filename}
```

The error code I receive is
BytesReceived="0", ErrorCode="Reached the end of the file.
(0x80070026)"

Headers="Content-Type: text/html
Vary: Cookie
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
"

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on this error, I suggest you use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out! :)
The error code I receive is BytesReceived="0", ErrorCode="Reached the end of the file.
 (0x80070026)"

Comment: same thread: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/636268/django-chunked-upload-iis-10.html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/636268/django-chunked-upload-iis-10.html)